Is there any difference between AddScoped and AddSingleton in WPF?
In the context of WPF or any console application that does not run as a web app serving web requests, if I am using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection how are AddScoped and AddSingleton methods different?
After reading this question it got me thinking:
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>(); //how is this
        //services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>(); //different than this

        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
        services.AddScoped<MainWindow>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        MainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
}


In the case of main window you'd usually only have just the one instance meaning there's no practical difference.

Similarly, anything you inject into main window is going to be instantiated at start up, so it's only getting that one instance.

The difference is the same in all application types. If you create a scope, scoped services will be disposed when the scope ends, so the question becomes, do you need a scope in WPF? The answer is yes, but there's no automatic way to create one.  If you create a scope around a business operation you can ensure eg that DbContext or other Unit-of-Work implementations terminate when the operation itself completes

There is a difference! Let's say for example you have a custom navigation (which you should do) in the WPF with AddSingleton on Views (User Control) and on VM (View model class). That way whenever user navigates between Views, the Views as well as the VM data is kept in a memory and do not need to be reloaded/recreated. If you use AddScoped, the instances would be cleaned as some point and in navigation the recreation of them might happen (depending on the GC).
OF course, if we are talking MainWindow as an example, the probability that you will need to recreate that is close to zero and in that particular case I would say there are no differences
